# Retrieve multiple values in a sharepoint designer workflow

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, return-value, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

Here my problem:

I have Two SharePoint lists:

**Projects:**

```
Project Name     Project Manager
  Project1           Name 1
  Project2           Name 2
```

**DevTeams:**

```
Project(Lookup)   Developer
   Project1         Name 1
   Project1         Name 2
   Project2         Name 3
```

I am getting the following warning message when I try to retrieve field values based on a condition in SharePoint Designer.

***The lookup that you defined is not guaranteed to return a single value. If more than one value is returned, only the first value will be used.***

But in my case, the condition satisfies multiple items and would like to return all the values. How to accomplish that?

I'll explain...When a user creates an item in a third list, my workflow sends an approval to all the leaders of the projects in which the developer is assigned.

how can I retrieve multiple value?

Answer (score 0):

As you are on SharePoint 2013, you can use REST services for that.

Here is an example to get you started:

http://fabiangwilliams.wordpress.com/2013/09/04/using-the-call-http-web-service-rest-calls-in-sharepoint-online-using-spd/

In previous versions you had no other option than retrieving items one at a time.